# How to invert text color in TextField depending on background

Tags: ios, swift, colors, uitextfield, uistoryboard

I have thumbnail image with TextField on it which shows the video length. How could I make it different from various background (thumbnail) colors?

[image: white is ok with blue back]

[image: how to invert text color when there is white background]

Comment: Do you have finite count of images or its just load from network?

Comment: I'm loading images from the network that's why they are always different :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add shadow for your label to prevent situation on screenshot:

```
label.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
label.layer.shadowRadius = 0
label.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
label.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: -1)
```

Comment: Artem, thank you for your response! The plan is that I have **TextField** not Label and I want to make it looking like on youtube with dimmed translucent background! How do you think is it possible to realize it?

Comment: Or Label would be better for this purpose?

Comment: You need to use `UITextField` if you're waiting user input. For showing of time you can use `UILabel`. I've watched Youtube app, there is able with transparent background and 1 pt border. You can create same UI for your time information

Answer (score 2):

I decided to do all this stuff in Storyboard and finally, my solution is:

- set background color to LightGray with Opacity 50% in Attributes inspector-View-Background-Other
- mark "Clip to Bounds" below
- add this two lines in Identity inspector-User Defined Runtime Attributes :

[image: User Defined Runtime Attributes]

And the result is:

[image: result]